# Editing Fromset ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When i edit formset the ModelChoiceField don't show initial value (it show the empty label). I use this example 
https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html

demande\forms.py

```
class LinkForm(forms.Form):
    etabz = forms.ModelChoiceField(empty_label="Choisir un établissement",\
queryset=Etablissement.objects.all().order_by('univ','etablissement').distinct(),
                         )
    # etabz = forms.CharField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dbz = kwargs.pop("dbz", None)
        super(LinkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if dbz:
           self.fields["etabz"].queryset = Etablissement.objects.filter(univ__corps=dbz)



class BaseLinkFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):

        if any(self.errors):
            return

        anchors = []
        urls = []
        duplicates = False

        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data:
                dona = form.cleaned_data.get('etabz')
                anchor = dona.etablissement
                if anchor :
                    if anchor in anchors:
                        duplicates = True
                    anchors.append(anchor)

                if duplicates:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Vous ne pouvez choisir le même établissement plusiuers fois.',
                    code='duplicate_etab'
                )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseLinkFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False
```

Demande\views.py

```
@login_required
def demande(request):
    user = request.user
    corpsorigine = user.profile.corps
    uz = get_object_or_404(session, active=True, destine = user.profile.corps)
    choice_links = choix.objects.filter(demandeur = user, session = uz )
    link_data = [{'etabz': l}
        for l in choice_links]
    LinkFormSet = formset_factory(LinkForm, formset=BaseLinkFormSet, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        link_formset = LinkFormSet(request.POST,form_kwargs={'dbz':corpsorigine })
        if link_formset.is_valid():
            new_links = []
            for link_form in link_formset:
                dona = link_form.cleaned_data.get('etabz')
                try:
                    univ = dona.univ
                    etablissementa = dona.etablissement
                except:
                    messages.error(request, 'Une exception à provoqué une erreur. veuillez ré-essayer ultérieurement')
                    return redirect(reverse('blog:post_list'))

                if  etablissementa and univ:
                    new_links.append(choix(demandeur = user,session=uz.annee_session, etablissement_demande=etablissementa, universite_demande=univ))
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    UserLink = choix.objects.all()
                    UserLink.filter(session= uz.annee_session,demandeur = user).delete()
                    UserLink.bulk_create(new_links)
                    messages.success(request, 'Votre demande à été correctement saisie/mis à jour.')
                    return redirect(reverse('blog:post_list'))

            except IntegrityError:  # If the transaction failed
                messages.error(request, 'Une exception à provoqué une erreur. veuillez ré-essayer ultérieurement')
                return redirect(reverse('blog:post_list'))
    else:
        link_formset = LinkFormSet(initial=link_data,form_kwargs={'dbz':corpsorigine })
    context = {
        'uz':uz,
        'link_formset': link_formset,
        'choice_links':choice_links
    }
return render(request, 'edit_pro.html', context)
```

Account\Models.py

```
class universite (models.Model):
    gouvernorat= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    universite = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    corps =  models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=corps_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('gouvernorat', 'universite')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.universite

 class etablissement(models.Model):
    etablissement = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    univ = models.ForeignKey(universite, related_name='etab_universites')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} de l'universite {}".format(self.etablissement,self.univ)
```

Demande\models.py

```
class choix(models.Model):
    demandeur = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_choice')
    # universite_demande = models.ForeignKey(universite, related_name='universite_choice')
    session = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    universite_demande = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    etablissement_demande = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('demandeur', 'session','etablissement_demande')
    def __unicode__(self):
         return "{} de l'universite {}".format(self.etablissement_demande, self.universite_demande)
```

In demande\forms.py If i change forms.ModelChoiceField... to forms.CharField it works perfectly. How it can works on ModelChoiceField ?

Comment: Form.initial should be a dictionary not a list of dictionaries

Comment: ink_data = {'etabz': choice_links} ?? doesn't work :

Comment: any idea ? help please.